# IQueryable queried data count

Tags: c#, count, iqueryable

I am trying to get the count of the items as I'm applying a query to a IQueryable.

I'am trying to do it like:

```
this.lblSth.Text = new Repository<Sth>().GetAll().Where(p => p.PersonId == personId).ToList().Count().ToString();
```

I think this gets all the data across the condition and takes the objects, then it takes the count; so I'm curious if for example I'd just take the Id columns and cast it to the list or some other smart way; that count operation would be quicker?

Info: GetAll() => It's a repository pattern method that returns IQueryable objects T from linqToSql data entity.

I'm open to all types of different ideas. Thanks

Comment: Is this querying a database?  If so, via what technology?  Linq2SQL?  EF?

Comment: @ChrisShain it is included in the question that it is LinqToSql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the call to Where and ToList is redundant.
see below.

```
this.lblSth.Text = new Repository<Sth>().GetAll().Count(p => p.PersonId == personId).ToString();
```

Comment: @TGH yeah but if calling only count as a lambda does the job, why would i want to add the where? feels redundant ... less typing at least :)

Comment: Yes I agree with that I missed your change to Count :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this quicker, just don't call `ToList()`:

```
this.lblSth.Text = new Repository<Sth>().GetAll()
                                        .Where(p => p.PersonId == personId)
                                        .Count()
                                        .ToString();
```

This way, (assuming it's an SQL-backed `IQueryable<T>`) it will execute a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM …`, not `SELECT * FROM …` like your approach. And this query should be much faster.

Comment: alright, is it quicker to just take Id of it or it is almost same?

Comment: That could depend on your `IQueryable` provider and your database negine, but I doubt it will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

ToList() will execute the query and turn your IQUeryable into IEnumerable. I would call the count on the where clause. That way the Count will become part of the end query

Comment: A good way to visualize this is to hook it up to db profiler. IF this is SQL Server you can you SQL Server profiler